# Why don't we use decimal in computers?

Tags: binary

Why is binary preferred in a computer system? Wouldn't it make more sense to use the more familiar decimal system instead?

Comment: Come up with a 10-state transistor and we'll talk.

Comment: This is a question about computer science moreso than mathematics.

Comment: As a proud Babylonian, I request a sexagesimal-based computer.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764439/why-binary-and-not-ternary-computing. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because binary lends itself naturally to a ON-OFF system where ON means a current and OFF means no current. Using 10 different voltage levels would be very error prone.

You could use binary numbers to represent decimal digits (this is called BCD). This has some advantages in some specific cases (like calculations using money, where a rounding error is prohibited).

Overall, the binary system wins because it is the easiest to design circuits with and the easiest to analyze and implement.

Comment: In a business context, BCD can perform better.  This is because there is often lots of I/O but relatively little arithmetic.  So, you gain more by the simpler conversion to and from human readable form than you lose on the slower arithmetic.  However, the primary motivation is, as you say, exactness in a financial context.